# Java3D Transfrom3D rotation not accurate

Tags: rotation, java-3d

I've the following problem. I want to draw a cylinder in Java3D between two spheres. Both located at (-1,-1,-1) and (1,1,1).

so I wrote the following method:

```
public TransformGroup buildJoint(double sx,double sy,double sz,double ex,double ey,double ez)
{
    TransformGroup transformGroup=new TransformGroup();
    transformGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);

    // Get the cylinder size
    double cylinderSize=Math.sqrt((ex-sx)*(ex-sx)+(ey-sy)*(ey-sy)+(ez-sz)*(ez-sz));

    // 1st Relocation for the cylinder size offset 
    Transform3D relocateT3D=new Transform3D();
    Vector3d relocate=new Vector3d(0,cylinderSize/2,0);
    relocateT3D.setTranslation(relocate);

    //2nd Relocation to place the cylinder at the start point
    Transform3D move3D=new Transform3D();
    Vector3d move=new Vector3d(sx,sy,sz);
    move3D.setTranslation(move);        
    move3D.mul(relocateT3D);                

    move3D.rotZ(-Math.PI/4.f);                  // Rotate the cylinder 45gr around Z axis

    Transform3D roty3D=new Transform3D();
    roty3D.rotY(-Math.PI/4.f);                  // Rotate the cylinder 45gr around Y axis
    roty3D.mul(move3D);

    transformGroup.setTransform(roty3D);

    Cylinder cylinder=new Cylinder(0.05f,(float) cylinderSize);
    transformGroup.addChild(cylinder);
    return transformGroup;
}
```

I call this function with:
TransformGroup joint=buildJoint(-1,-1,-1,1,1,1);

But the funny thing is that somehow both ends of the cylinder does not end up inside the middle of the spheres. There is an inaccuracy of about 0.2 rad.

Does someone has an idea what happens here?

Comment: Which version of Java3D do you use? How do you measure the inaccuracy?

Comment: Java 1.9 with Java 3D 1.5. 
The two Sphere are placed at (-1,-1,-1) and (1,1,1). When I make a straight line of ColorCube's they end up exactly in the middle of the spheres

Comment: Sorry but Java3D 1.5.2 hasn't been maintained since ten years, please switch to Java3D 1.6.0. Ok but it doesn't tell me how you compute the inaccuracy of 0.2 rad.

Comment: 0.2 rad is an estimate. I did a recalculation. The sphere is at -4,-4,-4 the start of the cylinder is at -3,620557, -4,839110 ,-3,643471. The difference is less, around 0.02 rad. But even the. The cylinder is outside the sphere.

Also interestring is the transform matrix after the two rotations

0.5000000000000001, 0.5, -0.7071067811865475, 0.0
-0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865476, 0.0, 0.0
0.5, 0.4999999999999999, 0.7071067811865476, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0

It looks to me that both rotations did an equal job.

Comment: JavaFX gives the same issue.